# How to check if a excel cell contains a word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, wildcard

I am looking for an excel formula that either counts or returns true if the cell contains a word pattern (basically wanted to know if any such cell exists), but formula shall recognize a cell as valid only if

Requirement 1 : complete word pattern to be present and as a single word in the cell being checked(Eg: if ab12 is pattern, ab123 is not valid, only ab12 is valid)

Requirement 2 : the matching word can be either in the beginning or end or in middle of the cell being checked

Requirement 3 : The input cell(s) being checked may contain this matching word and can contain prefix/suffix as " "(space) or a line break/feed . Hence, the formula shall identify this cell as valid for both these scenarios

Example word pattern : ab-1_cd_1234

At the moment I have tried both formulas below (also tried with " ","*","~" in the criteria) but didnt work  :

Formula 1 : =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2))

```
          Here, A2 is the pattern, B2 is the input to verify and will be verified in full B column
```

Formula 2 : =COUNTIF($B:$B, "* " &A2& " *")

```
          Here, B:B is the input column and A2 is the pattern
```

Also, I got to know that there is a wildcard in word < and > that defines a word beginning and end, but the same didnt work in excel.

So, it would be great if I can get any formula that works in excel

Comment: Can you explain more about requirement 3? And in particular your example. What is the pattern you wish to find right there?

Comment: Yes, please do remove the ambiguity from your question. After making clear that you want to look for `ab12` (but not "ab123") at the beginning, middle or end of a cell, you continue that `ab12` might "contain prefix/suffix as " "(space) or a line break/feed". In fact, `ab12` can't "contain" anything, especially not a prefix or suffix which are prefixed or appended by their nature. To put icing on the cake you then quote "ab-1_cd_1234" as an example, which looks like an example of the same "ab123" you expressly exclude. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @JvdV - A cell as you know may contain more than one line, and if the pattern that I am searching is in the beginning of a new line (in a cell), then there wont be a space before this, it would be a line feed. Similarly when the same word if its present at the end of the line (line feed will be after the end of the word and not a space). In all other scenarios the cell would contain text something like "...text.... Word-that-matches-the-pattern ....text...". The pattern that I wanted to search is as told in my example : ab-1_cd_1234

Comment: @Variatus - I wish your query is cleared based on my previous comment.And, FYI, the cells that I am searching will not only contain a single word. It may be a group of words or a group of lines with several texts out of which I am searching a word with particular pattern. Updated the query and hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2=FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")," ","</b><b>") & "</b></a>","//b")))>0
```

**Edit**

To solve problem with empty strings:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2 & "#"=FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),"#</b><b>")," ","#</b><b>") & "#</b></a>","//b")))>0
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**
To count number of cells which contains pattern you can use array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(SEARCH(" " & A2 & " "," " & SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$10,CHAR(10)," ") & " "),0)>0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked for most of my inputs but for some cases it throws #VALUE!. Also, hopefully the formula suggested in generic, as the pattern 'ab-1_cd_1234' is just an example (Note : I dont know what <a><b> in formula means and guess its not the starting two characters of the pattern)
The formula didnt work for the following scenarios (given within "") in cells and throws #value! error

Scenario 2 : A space present in the end of the following scenario
"This is first line scenario 2 : ab-1_cd_1234 "

Comment: Also,Scenario 7 : Not sure, but I Guess your formula works only when the matching pattern exists only at the beggining and at the end of the full text of a cell.
"The text ab-1_cd_1234  is present"

Scenario 8 : Cell containing only the word but with space at last
"ab-1_cd_1234 "

Scenario 9 : Cell containing only the word but with space at beginning and last
" ab-1_cd_1234 "

Scenario 10 : Cell containing line breaks before and after the matching pattern
"
ab-1_cd_1234
"

Comment: The formula finds the word anywhere in the text, but the problem occurs if the text has multiple spaces in a row (or at start or at end of text). This can be solved by adding a symbol at the end of the search word that does not appear in the text itself. In the corrected example, this is '#'.

Comment: Thanks. Your formula work for the scenario but I couldnt generalise it for series of input cells. As you see in my formula 2 : =COUNTIF($B:$B, "* " &A2& " *"). Here pattern in A2 is searched across B:B (but couldnt meet other requirements). Can you please let me know if there is a wayforward by modifying your formula to verify series of cells also?

Comment: The updated formula is working for all requirements except for full word check(requirement 1). Eg: in your screenshot for row 10 instead of 'ab-1_cd_1234' if you provide 'ab-1_cd_12341', then still it considers as valid input. Same case if something is added in the beginning of the word

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula, where A3 is a text to be searched and the text to be found is in A1.

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" "&$A$1&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(10)," ")&" ")),"",TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks. But, it didnt work for the following scenarios

a) abdccddab-1_cd_1234 : scenario 3


b) scenario 4 : abdccddab-1_cd_1234

where, the search pattern is a part of another word, which I dont want to be included.

Comment: One picture better than a thousand words. Now I understood what you need. :-)  I have amended my formula. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the scenario I mentioned. But, can you please tell me if this formula can be modified such that it can be verified for full column? As you see my formula 2 originally had COUNTIF and I could parse through full B:B column to verify pattern in A2 (but could not match the full word though). And, your formula at the moment only can check input cell A3 here

Comment: If you think in terms of a helper column, my formula can be used in that column's row 3 if you change "A3" to "B3" and place the string pattern in A1 . Copy from row 3 to all rows used in column B and use COUNTIF to count the TRUE results in the helper and display them in, say, B1. The advantage of a helper column would be that you can use it to highlight the offenders with CF. However, if you just want a single formula in B1 to give the same result without a helper column a function capable of looping must be deployed. Please confirm that that is what you want and I shall have a go at it.

Comment: Yes, I wanted for several cells. But, I got a solution. Appreciate your support, thanks

Comment: In fairness to myself and other viewers please post your solution and mark it as selected.

Comment: yes, please see the same post where I have selected as answer